# Matching center of two elements using html and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am new to css, I have span element of different width i.e, they have contents of different length ( for ex: 9,56 and 90). I want to make sure center of select element and span element match every time.

Note : In future I might have span of various lengths in each case I want the centers of select and span match automatically.

Here is the picture of What I need
[image]

Currently what I have

[image]

```css
.floatright {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height:500px;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    
}
select {
    text-indent: 140px !important;
}
select option {
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="floatright">
       <select style="width:320px;">
           <option>class 1</option>
           <option>class 2</option>
           <option>class 1</option>
           <option>class 2</option>
           <option>class 1</option>
           <option>class 2</option>
        </select>
    <div>
        <span>jefsyadlmu</span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <span>uirkvcnyuimuamjkznvuozaeff</span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <span>inwulpbkmnthllkpwdeygewehnpxaearnbmmzidtimcfvzrvwjfpodkinhybsneirbi</span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

    </div>
    </div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add `div{text-align:center;}` to your CSS.

But please note that your HTML is quite wrong. You're not supposed to use `<span>` and `<br>` to achieve this, it would be much better to use `<p>`'s instead. That way you could even define precisely how many pixels you want as a space between your sentences.

```css
.floatright {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height:500px;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    
}
select {
    text-indent: 140px !important;
}
select option {
    font-weight: bold !important;}
div { text-align:center;}
p {margin-bottom:40px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="floatright">
       <select style="width:320px;">
           <option>class 1</option>
           <option>class 2</option>
           <option>class 1</option>
           <option>class 2</option>
           <option>class 1</option>
           <option>class 2</option>
        </select>
    <div>
        <p>jefsyadlmu</p>
        <p>uirkvcnyuimuamjkznvuozaeff</p>
  <p>inwulpbkmnthllkpwdeygewehnpxaearnbmmzidtimcfvzrvwjfpodkinhybsneirbi</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll avoid using `position: absolute` at all cost, you could achieve what you want just using ´flex´ bass CSS and adding another class for the wrapper of the text (In my case called `wrapper`), as the below snippet shows:

```css
.floatright {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height:500px;
  right:0px;
  top:0px;  
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

select {
  text-indent: 140px !important;
}

select option {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="floatright">
       <select style="width:320px;">
           <option>class 1</option>
           <option>class 2</option>
           <option>class 1</option>
           <option>class 2</option>
           <option>class 1</option>
           <option>class 2</option>
        </select>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <span>jefsyadlmu</span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <span>uirkvcnyuimuamjkznvuozaeff</span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <span>inwulpbkmnthllkpwdeygewehnpxaearnbmmzidtimcfvzrvwjfpodkinhybsneirbi</span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

    </div>
    </div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `body { text-align: center; }` or `margin: 0 auto` to all of your elemets

Answer (score 1):

Just add this text-align:center; to your class .floatright, and also it is better with flexbox, you can find some tutorials on youtube to see how it works.

```
.floatright {
position: absolute;
width: 500px;
height:500px;
right:0px;
top:0px;
text-align: center;

}
```